# MoqMockingKernel: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated by type

Tags: c#, ninject, moq, ninject-extensions

I try to use the MoqMockingKernel class. (Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq) from the Ninject.MockingKernel Extension for a unit test.

At initializing the MoqMockingKernel I'm getting the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance
>   security rules violated by type:
>   'Ninject.MockingKernel.MockingKernel'. Derived types must either match
>   the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible..

My initializing code:

```
        private MoqMockingKernel mockingKernel;
        private Mock<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkMock;
        private IExternalServiceRepository externalServiceRepository;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.mockingKernel = new MoqMockingKernel();
            this.mockingKernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToMock();

            this.unitOfWorkMock = this.mockingKernel.GetMock<IUnitOfWork>();

            externalServiceRepository = new ExternalServiceRepository { Kernel = this.mockingKernel };
        }
```

How can I solve this `TypeLoadException`?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using .Net framework >= 4.0?

See this [conversation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/b84aad34-cef4-4045-9111-3fd3a66a5789)

I took advice from those instructions: I modified MockingKernel source code by adding this line

> [assembly:
>   System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]

to AssemblyInfo.cs in projects Ninject.MockingKernel and Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq.
Then I recompiled solution, installed dll's and my code started to work!

I hope this is the trick for you.