# "Inheritance security rules violated" when running project with Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have an application I'm working on with references to `log4net`, `Ninject`, `Ninject.Extensions.Logging`,  and `Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4net`. When I attempt to run the application, I receive an exception:

```
{"Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'Ninject.Extensions.Logging.LoggerModuleBase'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.":"Ninject.Extensions.Logging.LoggerModuleBase"}
```

I'm completely new to Ninject and the logging extension. I've seen [several](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b84aad34-cef4-4045-9111-3fd3a66a5789/inheritance-security-rules-violated-when-switching-to-40?forum=vsto) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286799/moqmockingkernel-system-typeloadexception-inheritance-security-rules-violated) around that involve adding something like:

```
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

But I fail to see what the actual problem is and why I should need to modify release source code to coalesce with my application. Thus, I am under the assumption that I am doing something wrong. What could the problem possibly be?

For more information, the application is built targeting .Net 4 instead of the .Net 4 Client Profile, I've tried targeting both the Client Profile and the full .Net 4 framework while building the extension, but neither has worked.

I'm building the release version of the extension using the provided .sln file (not the nAnt build file). The extension project can be found on [Github](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging).

I'm running Visual Studio 2010.

My kernel is built like so:

```
private static StandardKernel kernel;
public static StandardKernel Kernel
{
    get
    {
        return kernel;
    }
}

public static void BuildKernel()
{
    var settings = new NinjectSettings
    {
        LoadExtensions = false
    };

    var modules = new INinjectModule[]
    {
        new MainModule(),
        new Log4NetModule()
    };

    kernel = new StandardKernel(settings, modules);
}
```

My log4net configuration is rather basic, but here is my full app.Config file:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="BasicAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <threshold value="Warn"/>
      <file value="Logs/errorlog.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <header value="[Basic Appender]&#13;&#10;" />
        <footer value="[Basic Appender]&#13;&#10;" />
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] &lt;%property{auth}&gt; - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="BasicAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure what caused the error, but update to the version available via Nuget fixed it. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4net/3.0.1